# mod_wsgi with two python versions

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an `Ubuntu-18.04 LTS` EC2 serving a django application with `mysql  Ver 8.0.16`, `Apache/2.4.29` and `mod_wsgi/4.6.5`complied with`python3.6`. Now, I am targeting to deploy a new django application in the same Ubuntu EC2 serve and it requires `python3.11+` virtualenv for installing its requirements.txt, now i am facing issues while deploying the new application.

here are few other informations, Using Pyenv for creating virtualenvs, mod_wsgi is installed from source and compiled using `./configure --with-python=/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/python3.6`

after deploying the new django application the domain returns 500 error and logs are as follows

api.log

```
[03/Aug/2023:18:42:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
[03/Aug/2023:18:43:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
[03/Aug/2023:18:43:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
[03/Aug/2023:18:43:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
[03/Aug/2023:18:43:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
[03/Aug/2023:18:43:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 816
```

api_error.log

```
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047679 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]  mod_wsgi (pid=170353): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047724 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]  mod_wsgi (pid=170353): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047795 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047810 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]    File "/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047814 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.047827 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140404074731072]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180781 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]  mod_wsgi (pid=170353): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180819 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]  mod_wsgi (pid=170353): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180886 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180900 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]    File "/var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180904 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Aug 03 18:43:18.180916 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 170353:tid 140403957233216]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
```

here is the apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName qa.api.domian.com
WSGIDaemonProcess qa.api.domian.com python-home=/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/envs/timesheet_env python-path=/var/www/project
    WSGIProcessGroup qa.api.domian.com
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
DocumentRoot /var/www/project

    ErrorLog "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_error.log"
    CustomLog "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api.log" common
    LogLevel Warn

    Alias /static /var/www/project/static
    <Directory /var/www/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/newdjango/wsgi.py
<Directory "/var/www/project/newdjango">
<Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

according to the mod_wsgi documentation and from my research, the issue is due to difference in python version of virtualenv and mod_wsgi, please correct me if i am wrong.

Now i am targeting to deploy both django application `old-django should use python3.6.8` and `new-django should use python3.11+`

i tried compiling the `mod_wsgi` with `python3.11`

- downloaded latest `mod_wsgi/4.9.4` from source
- ./configure --with-python=/shims/python3.11
- make, make install

after compiling the new django app works perfectly but existing django fails with same errors

now can anyone suggest me the steps for resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to serve the two django application with two independent docker containers and to use the existing Apache server as a proxy.